# Unable to put an image beside checkbox which are generated dynamically

Tags: jquery

Please look at the http://jsfiddle.net/aJZUG/

I am trying to display image beside checkbox as shown below using which are being generated dynamically based on the xml file

I have used , but its not displaying the image beside checkbox

```
 append('<input type="img" height="40" width="40" src="'+image[i]+"<br/>") ;
```

could anybody please tell me why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some typos

1. Element should be `<img/>`
2. You need to close the quote and the element `src="'+image[i]+'"/>`

---

```
activateUiHTML.append('<img type="img" src="'+image[i]+'"/><br/>') ;
//                      ^^^ img                        ^^^^ quote and element
```

Comment: Thanks its working , Is it possible to display image and checkbox in one line ??

Comment: Thank you very very much , i guess i need to remove the br to get displayed in one single line .Thanks once again .